# Como desplegar una posición específica en un elemento select en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una rutina que al presionar un botón, genera en forma dinámica una fila con dos elementos: un elemento combo desplegable (select), el cual contiene una lista de artículos y un elemento input:

```
<select class="cmb_articulo" id="cmb_articulo" name="articulo[]" style="width:180px">
<?php 
    $sql1 = "SELECT id_articulo, articulo, descripcion FROM articulos ORDER BY articulo";
    $q1 = mysqli_query( $con, $sql1) or die("Problemas al ejecutar la consulta");
    echo '<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Seleccione el Artículo</option>';
    while($qq1=mysqli_fetch_array($q1))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$qq1['id_articulo'].'">'.$qq1['articulo'].'</option>';
    }
?>  
</select>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="txtstock" id="txtstock" name="txtstock[]" readonly="readonly" value=0 style="width:75px"/>
</td>
```

Cuando se genera este combo select, aparece seleccionado "Seleccione el Artículo".

Una vez que el usuario pincha el combo select, se despliega la lista y el usuario selecciona una opción.
Para la opción seleccionada, se desarrolla una lógica en donde muestra en el input un valor.

Si para la opción seleccionada, la lógica determina que no se puede mostrar un valor en el input, el combo select debería quedar como al principio, mostrando la opción "Seleccione el Artículo". Es este último caso el que no he podido implementar, es decir, dejar el combo select como cuando recién se despliega. He intentado lo siguiente, pero no me ha funcionado:

```
$row.find("td:eq(0)").find("select").option('-1');
```

Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Alternativamente se puede usar `.attr('selected', 'selected');`, en vez del `prop("selected", true);`

```js
$(function(){
  $("#resetLeSelect").on("click", function(){
    $("#cmb_articulo option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select class="cmb_articulo" id="cmb_articulo" name="articulo[]" style="width:180px">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Seleccione el Artículo</option>
<option value="1">Art 1</option>
<option value="2">Art 2</option>
<option value="3">Art 3</option>
<option value="4">Art 4</option>
<option value="5">Art 5</option>
</select>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="txtstock" id="txtstock" name="txtstock[]" readonly="readonly" value=0 style="width:75px"/>
</td>

<button id="resetLeSelect">Click para reset</button>
```

Edit: tal vez no resulte obvio en el ejemplo dado así que prueba esto

```
$row.find("td:eq(0)").find("select option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: No funciona. 
Como cada línea tiene un elemento select y un elemento input text, pudiendo haber muchas líneas , entonces:
$row.find("td:eq(0)").find("select").  hace referencia al primer elemento, es decir el select.
$row.find("td:eq(1)").find("input").val(respuesta.cantidad);  , hace referencia al segundo elemento, es decir el input text.
Lo único que me falta es saber qué agregar en:
$row.find("td:eq(0)").find("select").
Para que el select quede mostrando la primera posición que está deshabilitada con el mensaje "Seleccione el Artículo".

Comment: tu `$row.find("td:eq(0)").find("select")` es el `$("#cmb_articulo)` del ejemplo

Comment: Alo Malbarez, perfecto, ahora funcionó. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Junco Fuerte Deberías aceptar la respuesta entonces :-)

Comment: Disculpa lo torpe que pueda parecer, pero cómo se hace para darle Aceptar a la respuesta?

Comment: debería aparecerte una marca de verificación justo debajo de las flechas de voto a la izquierda de la respuesta.